# How to get process command line arguments in execsnoop

Tags: macos, ps

I need to log the process start events with the command line arguments. 
There's ps au which prints the command line for the processes which are currently running.
There's execsnoop which prints the log of process start events, but it prints only process names.

How can I have execsnoop log with the command line arguments in it?

p.s. there must be some way to do this through writing D script for dtrace, but I'm not skilled enough to do it :(

Comment: The Linux version does it: see [here for example](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-28/execsnoop-for-linux.html). Even the [help](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/execsnoop.8.html) seems to say so.  Are you sure you are not executing it with `-a 0` or something similar? Check [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/perf-tools-unstable) if you can find a version that may run on your computer...

Comment: yet MacOs version of exescoop doesn't print the command line :(

Comment: Did you tried to download the [source file .tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perf-tools-unstable/0.0.1~20150130+git85414b0-1) and compile for your OS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work for a certain number of arguments: `sudo dtrace /usr/bin/newproc.d`

You will need to turn off System Integrity Protection for this to work.

Comment: dtrace: no probes specified - it's MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: I think this is missing `-s`. `sudo dtrace -s /usr/bin/newproc.d` works for me.